# Maria Database (Mariadb) - Aborted connection to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unathenticated' host: '127.0.0.1'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mariadb, warning

I am running an Ubuntu based LEMP mail/web server, using MariaDB.
When I run the command

```
sudo service mariadb status
```

I get the following warnings:

```
Oct 24 00:32:44 mail.example.com mariadbd[1226]: 2022-10-24  0:32:44 7610 [Warning] Aborted connection 7610 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Oct 24 00:32:44 mail.example.com mariadbd[1226]: 2022-10-24  0:32:44 7611 [Warning] Aborted connection 7611 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Oct 24 00:32:44 mail.example.com mariadbd[1226]: 2022-10-24  0:32:44 7612 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Oct 24 00:32:44 mail.example.com mariadbd[1226]: 2022-10-24  0:32:44 7613 [Warning] Aborted connection 7613 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Oct 24 00:32:44 mail.example.com mariadbd[1226]: 2022-10-24  0:32:44 7614 [Warning] Aborted connection 7614 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Oct 24 00:32:44 mail.example.com mariadbd[1226]: 2022-10-24  0:32:44 7615 [Warning] Aborted connection 7615 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
Oct 24 00:32:44 mail.example.com mariadbd[1226]: 2022-10-24  0:32:44 7616 [Warning] Aborted connection 7616 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

Could someone please explain what exactly is happening here, how to debug this, and how to fix these warnings? Is this a security issue or a functionality issue? Any elaboration, explanation, and solution here, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Having a similar issue. I'll post here if I can find a solution.